# Entries count by date is giving wrong results

Tags: mysql, count, datetime

I am getting some strange results with below queries:

```
SELECT count(id)
FROM `asins`
WHERE `StockUpdated` >= '2016-12-30'
and  `StockUpdated` <= '2016-12-31'
```

The result is : 24446

```
SELECT count(id)
FROM `asins`
WHERE `StockUpdated` >= '2016-12-30'
```

The result is : 33098

```
SELECT count(id)
FROM `asins`
WHERE `StockUpdated` >= '2016-12-30'
and `StockUpdated` <= '2017-1-1'
```

The result is : 33098

```
SELECT count(id)
FROM `asins`
WHERE `StockUpdated` >= '2017-1-1'
```

The result is : 0

My question is why the below query is not perfect?

```
SELECT count(id)
FROM `asins`
WHERE `StockUpdated` >= '2016-12-30'
and  `StockUpdated` <= '2016-12-31'
```

Comment: What timezone are you in?  What is the datatype of `StockUpdated`?

Answer (score 5):

Looks like `StockUpdated` has a time part that makes the query not count the values on `2016-12-31` with time other than `00:00`.

Try a non inclusive comparison instead. `StockUpdated < '2017-01-01'`

Comment: Yes, +1. `StockUpdated` is either a `datetime` or a `timestamp` and not a `date` as the "weird results" conclusion assumes. The results only prove that that there are exactly (33098-24446)=8652 rows that are `> '2016-12-30'` and `< '2017-01-01'`, so as this answer says, have a time other than 00:00:00.